# Emitted Signal Isn't Detected

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I tried to emit signal `finished()` from my class. But when I'm connecting the signal to my slot, it didn't do anything.

My class' name is `blend_install`, I declared it as `blendinstaller` and tried to connect that to the QEventLoop.

```
....
QEventLoop ac;
connect(&blendinstaller, SIGNAL(finished()), &ac, SLOT(quit()));

blendinstaller.show_progress();
blendinstaller.download(); // this will execute everything and in the end emit finished()

ac.exec();
....
```

The `download()` function:

```
current_prog = BLEND_INSTALL_NONE;
emit progress_changed(current_prog);

manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;

file_handler = new QFile(downloadTo);

file_handler->open(QFile::WriteOnly);
.... handle error .... // each of this (error handling) will emit finished() signal and return;

.... // each of this will represent the process of reporting event changes (for logging), emit a SIGNAL()

QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl(downloadFrom));

reply = manager->get(request);
event = new QEventLoop;
connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),event,SLOT(quit()));
connect(reply,SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),this,SLOT(downloadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(reply,SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(downloadProgressL(qint64,qint64)));


event->exec();

.... handle error ....

.... write reply.readAll() to file ....

....

// these are instruction for a custom QProcess instance
proc.setProgram(extractWith);
proc.setArguments(ar);
proc.setWorkingDirectory(downloadIn);

event = new QEventLoop;
connect(&proc,SIGNAL(finished(int)),event,SLOT(quit()));
connect(&proc,SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),this,SLOT(extractError(QProcess::ProcessError)));
connect(&proc,SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),this,SLOT(extractFinished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));

proc.start();
proc.open_console();

event->exec();

.... handle error ....

....

.... attempt to find output of QProcess (extract an archive) ....

.... handle error, output of QProcess not found ....

....

emit installed(installOn);
emit finished(); // the SIGNAL I want to get.

qDebug("It's finished installing!");
```

So, TL;DR each of *errors handling* will return from the function but also emit `finished()` and in the end of function (assuming there is no error) it will emit `finished()`.

It won't quit the loop.

Any idea?

Comment: It does look fine. Can you post your `download()`implementation? I can only imagine that your `download()` method emits the `finished()` signal too early. Better said: It should not be called from it at all. Usually some kind of private slot `onDownloadComplete()` would emit the `finished()` signal.

Comment: @mfreiholz I've uploaded that, and I'll try your suggestion...

Comment: It's always print that "It's finished installing!" message, but still doesn't emit the `finished()` signal.

Comment: Please try to provide a shorter [mcve](/help/mcve) There seems to be a lot of unrelated code.

Comment: Side comment: try using Qt5 syntax for SIGNAL/SLOT, it was introduced 2 years ago and has many advantages over old syntax: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `download()` method is, that it is already a synchron method. You don't need this event loop. You already do everything in event loops inside your `download()` method.

**Side note:** And you seem to have some memory leaks, since you create QEventLoop without parent and never delete it.

**UPDATE #1:**
Your `finished()` event is not being handled by the outer QEventLoop (`ac`), because the `finished()` signal gets emitted before the QEventLoop even begins to handle events with `exec()`.
As a ugly workarround you could invoke `download()` after `exec()` with a queued `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` (Qt::QueuedConnection) call (but i would not recommend it).

**Update #2**
Here is a small example, which is not perfect, of course :P

```
class BlendDownloader
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  BlenDownloader() :
    _file(NULL)
  {
  }

  void download()
  {
    _file = new QFile("C:/myfile.blubb");

    QNetworkRequest req("your url here");
    QNetworkReply* reply = _mgr.get(req);
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onDownloadFinished()));
    // TODO: Also handle error callback here
  }

private slots:
  void onDownloadFinished()
  {
    QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    reply->deleteLater();

    // Write response data to file.
    // Note: You might get problems with big files,
    // since this buffers the entire response of QNetworkReply
    // in internal buffer. It's better to use the "readyRead()"
    // signal and write incrementally.
    _file->write(reply->readAll());

    // Do your parsing stuff now and emit "finished()" at the end.
    // ... parsing, validation here ...

    // Clean up
    _file->close();
    delete _file;
    _file = NULL;

    emit finished();
  }

private:
  QNetworkManager _mgr;
  QFile* _file;
};
```

Comment: It's a bunch of `QEventLoop` inside a `QEventLoop` because I need it to wait until everything is finished. But it might be because of the memory leak. I declared the QEventLoop on the private section of my class, is that bad?

Comment: @TitoNovelianto Why do you need to wait until everything is finished when you emit a `finished` signal? Just connect that `finished` signal to some slot where you do what you do after `loop->exec` (which seems like you are almost doing anyway).

Comment: I updated my answer with a small example (Update #2)

Comment: You have to delete the `QNetworkReply` object, otherwise there is a memory leak. [*Note: After the request has finished, it is the responsibility of the user to delete the QNetworkReply object at an appropriate time. Do not directly delete it inside the slot connected to finished(). You can use the deleteLater() function.*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#get). Also you can just create the `QFile` objejct on the stack in the `onDownloadFinished` function.

Comment: Thanks @thuga, I forgot that one :P I also added an important note to code comment, which is the reason why I added `_file` as member in this example.